# Run specific unit test in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have dozens of unit tests, and I'd like to fix the code I am working on now, but every time I run the tests it takes over 30 seconds to run every unit test (I think reflection is the cause of some of these being especially slow). My current test and many other tests take less than one second to run, but it is annoying to disable and then enable specific unit tests.

Is there a way to say, "For now, run a single, specific test?"

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with the built-in unit test system. I create tests by right-clicking any code and selecting "create unit test" which creates a project.

Comment: what unit testing framework do you use and what version of visual studio?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [Test Driven .Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) both have this feature in their visual studio test-runners. There may well be other VS plugins too.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266716/execute-only-one-unit-test-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008/266764#266764) (By Jon Skeet no less) it is possible in Visual studio natively too. To *debug* a single test:

> Click on a test method name, then press Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T. (Or go to Test / Debug / Tests in Current Context.)

EDIT: (based on a [comment from Justin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409055/run-specific-unit-test-in-visual-studios/4409067#comment16079960_4409067) below) to *run* a test (as opposed to debugging it) the command is simply:

> Ctrl+R, T

Comment: Awesome! That worked! (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T). `*clicks accept repeatably*`

Comment: Don't click it too often (at least, not an even number of times) - it toggles! :)

Comment: Note that Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T will *debug* the tests in the current context. Use Ctrl+R,T to just run.

Comment: Not sure why but for me this always runs/debugs all the tests in the class, not just the one particular test that was selected. The scope is incorrect. VS 2017, xUnit.

Comment: wow, I kept misreading it. Didn't realize that to debug I needed to lift my finger off the CTRL key, and then press it again... The shortcuts are almost identical.

Answer (score 35):

@Andrew M's answer is awesome, but I wanted to know where the keyboard shotcuts come from.  All you have to do is:

1. **Right click** your test function name.
2. Select **Run Test** or **Debug Test**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 5):

First, click somewhere inside the `TestMethod` you want to run, or highlight multiple methods. You can also click on the class or namespace if you want to run all `TestMethod`s within that class/namespace.

### Using The Test Tools Toolbar

1. Make sure the Test Tools Toolbar is visible (View → Toolbars → Test Tools).

[image: Visual Studio Test Tools Toolbar]

### Using The Test Menu

Run: Test → Run → Tests in Current Context 
Debug: Test → Debug → Tests in Current Context

### Using Shortcuts

Run: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>
Debug:<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

### Windows: Run unit tests with Test Explorer

> Use Test Explorer to run unit tests from Visual Studio or third-party unit test projects. You can also use Test Explorer to group tests into categories, filter the test list, and create, save, and run playlists of tests. You can debug tests and analyze test performance and code coverage. [more…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2019#run-tests-in-test-explorer)

1. Select one or more tests in Test Explorer
2. right-click → **Run Selected Tests** or **Debug Selected Tests**

[image: Run unit tests with Test Explorer on Windows]

---

### Mac: Run unit tests from Unit Test Pad or Text Editor

#### Option 1: Unit Test Pad

View → Pads → Unit Tests

> **Test**
>   Write high-quality code with testing tools. Visual Studio for Mac’s integrated test runner helps you run and debug unit tests and automated UI tests. [more…](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/)

Select one or more tests, right-click, **Run Test** or **Debug Test**.

[image: Run unit tests from Unit Test Pad on Mac]

#### Option 2: Text Editor Unit Test Integration

Visual Studio → Preferences → Text Editor → Source Analysis
☑ Enable text editor unit test integration

You can directly run a single test from directly from a *test* source file,

Answer (score 0):

Default Keyboard Shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for Debug

for Run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: If you look at the image, that's exactly what it says.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto this answer is for blind programmers ;)