# How to fix Project after sitting it as Startup with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, automation

When I try to run my first Selenium script in Visual Studio it gives me the message "a project with an out put type of class library cannot be started delicately".

I already set the project as my Startup project.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run specific unit test in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409055/run-specific-unit-test-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use class libraries independently you need to include in the different project by giving their reference after building them. This might help [Creating Class Libraries and Adding References to Assemblies](https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-41-creating-class-libraries-and-adding-references-to-assemblies)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the specifics of running a selenium script but this error comes when the output type of your project is not an executable.

If you right click on your project in VS, go to properties, in tab Application, you have a field called Output Type. In your project it is probably set to class library which cannot be executed. You need to change this to an executable type.