# How to run unit test from the text editor in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Is there any way to run unit tests directly from the text editor, somehow clicking/right clicking on the unit test source or left margin? (a la ReSharper)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when [CodeLens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2022) is enabled (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens).

It will show an indicator above the test, which can be clicked and shows Run and Debug options:
[image]

Alternatively, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409067/368354), it's also possible to do this via shortcuts: CTRL+R, T (Run) and CTRL+R, CTRL+T (Debug) by default.

Answer (score -1):

VS has a build in Test Explorer. Please go to Test --> Test Explorer.