# Command Test.DebugTestsInCurrentContext appears deprecated

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

#### TL;DR Can I still debug a test in the current context in VS11?

Unit testing using mstest in Visual Studio (verified in 2010 and 11, and even [2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266716/execute-only-one-unit-test-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008) apparently) has a command called `Test.DebugTestInCurrentContext`. It runs a single test in debug mode.

To use this command, you place your cursor anywhere in the method (the unit test in question) and then either

1  Use the (default) keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T`

or

2 Use the menu option Test=>Debug=>Tests in Current Context. (2010, don't know about 2008)

I'm now using VS 11 Beta, and found that hitting ^R,^T did nothing (is not a command). I checked the key bindings and found the command `Test.DebugTestInCurrentContext`, mapped it to ^R,^T as we expect, and tried again. This time the status bar reports:

`The key combination (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+T) is bound to (DebugTestsInCurrentContext) which is not currently available.`

Visual Studio 11 has a new Unit Test Explorer. After having run all tests once, it is populated with the solutions unit tests. At this point I am able to scroll...and scoll (I have a few tests), and find the one test I am interested in debug, and select it (highlight it). At this point I can right click => "Debug Selected Tests", or navigate the menu, Unit Tests=>Debug Unit Tests=>Selected Tests.

Thus, I have found I can debug a single unit test in VS11 by

1 Find the unit test in the unit test explorer after having run all tests

2 Select it

3 Execute "Debug Selected Tests"

Is there an easier way? Can I not use the old command to debug tests in the current context? Is that command obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to ask my question on the msdn forums. I got a response, in short: "the feature is broken in beta, will be back in rtm"

Read the full answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstest/thread/25dfe15d-d9a6-4e02-9962-c50faecaecd5/#25dfe15d-d9a6-4e02-9962-c50faecaecd5).

Comment: Still seems to be broken in RTM, though :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the following commands for keyboards shortcuts in newer versions of Visual Studio

- TestExplorer.DebugAllTestsInContext
- TestExplorer.RunAllTestsInContext

The following don't work anymore

- DebugTestInCurrentContext
- RunTestInCurrentContext

[Issue on Microsoft's site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745762/cant-run-or-debug-tests-in-current-context)